# Select only specific field from related object django

Tags: django, orm

I have these two models:

```
class Command(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    carrier = models.ForeignKey(Carrier, null=True, blank=True)
```

and

```
class Client(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

     some other fields ...
```

I have one object of the Command class let's call it `command`, let's assume I have this object **already**

I want to access to the `name` of the client of this command

I can do :

```
command.client.name
```

But the SQL expression generated is going to retrieve all the fields of the Client models while I only need `name`

I can do that to solve this problem:

```
from client.models import Client
name = Client.objects.only("name").get(command=command).name
```

But this is quite long to type, any fast way to do it ? something like `command.client.only("name").name` ?

Comment: How can be the `name` of `Client` is `ForeignKey` of the same model `Client`?

Comment: Thanks my mistake, it is corrected, name is a CharField

Answer (score 0):

You can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for this and chain it with values.

```
Command.objects.select_related('client').values('name')
```

This will output as a dict which can be referenced easily.

Comment: if you replace 'name' by 'client_name' yes it would work, 
 `Command.objects.select_related("client").values("client__name").get(pk = command.pk)["client__name"]` but longer than `Client.objects.only("name").get(command=command).name` which is already a bit too long to write

Comment: It's more standard method. Also it has better performance than yours one

Comment: I doubt it , the SQL generated is exactly the same, at the difference than your method doesn't return the id

Comment: related objects are cached that's why it gives better performance. I hope for single object you might get same performance but for a a bit large data you will see the improvements easily

Answer (score 0):

```
Command.objects.values('client__name')
```

Use double underscore to access related entity

Comment: If you have `Command` object , then you can directly access `command.client.name`.  What is your expectation exactly?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I explained , command.client.name will access it, but the SQL request generated by the django ORM will fetch all the fields of the client object